# calling Qt's QGraphicsView::setViewport with a custom QGLWidget

Tags: qt, opengl, qgraphicsview, qglwidget

I've derived from QGLWidget before, like so:

```
class MyGLWidget : public QGLWidget
{
public:
   // stuff...

   virtual void initializeGL() { /* my custom OpenGL initialization routine */ }

   // more stuff...
};
```

However, I find that if I try to initialize a QGraphicsView with my custom QGLWidget as the viewport, initializeGL doesn't get called (setting a breakpoint within the Qt library, neither does QGLWidget::initializeGL() when created plain).

```
// initializeGL, resizeGL, paintGL not called
ui.graphicsView->setViewport(new MyGLWidget(QGLFormat(QGL::DoubleBuffer)));

// initializeGL, resizeGL, paintGL *still* not called
ui.graphicsView->setViewport(new QGLWidget(QGLFormat(QGL::DoubleBuffer)));
```

Where is the correct location to place the code that currently resides in MyGLWidget::initializeGL()?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm going to go ahead and answer my own question.  This isn't optimal, but this is how I've gotten around the problem.

Instead of

```
ui.graphicsView->setViewport(new MyGLWidget(QGLFormat(QGL::DoubleBuffer)));
```

I've got this instead:

```
ui.graphicsView->setViewport(new QGLWidget(new CustomContext(QGLFormat(QGL::SampleBuffers))));
```

CustomContext is a class that derives from QGLContext.  I've overridden the create member, like so:

```
virtual bool create(const QGLContext *shareContext = 0)
{
    if(QGLContext::create(shareContext))
    {
        makeCurrent();

        /* do my initialization here */

        doneCurrent();

        return true;
    }

    return false;
}
```

I don't think this is the optimal way to do this, but it's better than the alternative of not having a specific initialization step at all.  I'd still be happy to have someone leave a better answer!

Answer (score 4):

The setupViewport slot of a custom QGraphicsView could be used to call updateGL() on the QGLWidget, which will cause initializeGL() to be called.

```
class MyGraphicsView : public QGraphicsView
{
    //... The usual stuff

protected slots:
    virtual void setupViewport(QWidget *viewport)
    {
        QGLWidget *glWidget = qobject_cast<QGLWidget*>(viewport);
        if (glWidget)
            glWidget->updateGL();
    }

};
```

Answer (score 2):

So what I've found is QGraphicsView installs a custom eventFilter on your QGLWidget viewport so it never sees the initialize/resize/repaint events.  This probably was done to make it work properly with drawBackground() etc.

My current best resolution is to catch the desired event either in QGraphicsView::resizeEvent()/etc, or install a custom eventFilter on your QGLWidget derived class to catch the resize/paint/etc events before QGraphicsView's custom eventFilter swallows them.

Answer (score 1):

The pain, the pain, ... integrating widgets derived from QGlWidgets into QGraphicsView is no fun, of the parts of Qt that I know this is definitely one of the messier areas. I ended up using a part of [kgllib](http://websvn.kde.org/trunk/playground/libs/kgllib/extras/kgllib/) (out of kde) called widgetproxy that is a very decent wrapper around a QGlWidget. I modified it to fit my needs but works reasonably well for most general cases where you want to use an exisiting class derived from QGlWidget inside a QGraphicsView and draw other things on top of it.

Answer (score 0):

`initializeGL()` won't get called until the first call to either `paintGL()` or `resizeGL()` and not when the widget is constructed. This may happen as late as when the widget is first made visible.

Comment: Here's the problem though: paintGL and resizeGL aren't being called either, since MyGLWidget is being used as the viewport, not as a widget added to the layout.  I should have been more specific in my question; I'll update it.